# seekg zero from current position resets eof flag

Tags: c++, istream

According to GCC 4.6.2 `istream.tcc`:

```
basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::
seekg(off_type __off, ios_base::seekdir __dir)
{
  // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
  // DR60.  Do not change _M_gcount.
  // Clear eofbit per N3168.
  this->clear(this->rdstate() & ~ios_base::eofbit);
```

I hit this accidentally -- and could not figure out why I was getting an infinite `while (!eof)` loop. Basically, when seekg is invoked with a ZERO length -- you still get the eof reset. Is there a reason for resetting the eof bit even for a zero length `std::ios_base_::cur` search? This does NOT happen in VC10/11.

And what is N3168?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are abusing `eof()`: the only use for this flag is to determine if you last read failed because you hit the end of the file (well, it doesn't even do that to be fair: even if `eof()` is set that may not be the real cause although it probably was). To determine the stream state use the conversion to `bool`:

```
while (in) ...
```

Note that you still need to check after reading if the read was successful.

[N3168](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2010/n3168.htm) is a paper discussed by the standardization committee. Off-hand I don't know what particular topic it discusses beyond that it was in response to a national body defect report.

Comment: The motivation for N3168 is, I think, that normally, if `eofbit` is set, then all further operations are required to fail.  Which means that if you read to the end of file, you can't seek back to an earlier point without first clearing `eof`.  The "correction" is to require the seek functions to reset `eofbit` before trying anything else.  Of course, if there has been failed input, you still have to clear before the seek, so I imagine that this problem is fairly rare (input an integer that is at the end of file, without any trailing whitespace, then seek).

Comment: But seekg-ing with a `0` offset from `ios_base::cur` should in theory have no effect. Or is there another reason why once a seekg is invoked, it goes all the way, regardless of the `pos` value.

Comment: The primary use of seeking to the current position is to change the stream into a state where it can be used either for reading or writing. Also, since seeking is intended to change the position, it seems reasonable to assume that the stream might not be at the end. I haven't looked at the paper but I fuess the change included potentially clearing `failbit`: as long as there is any bit set most operations are meant to fail.